# Sending Kendo grid row to server when click submit button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, c#-4.0, kendo-grid

I have an aspx page which has many html controls and a kendo grid on it. I want when the submit button is clicked all the data on the web form send to server. I know the the solution for the html controls but I cant send and probably convert to Json my Kendo grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the grid is in the Edit Mode then all you have to do is:

For sending the entire data on the grid:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your URL',
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; 
    charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify($("#GridName").data().kendoGrid._data)
});
```

For sending the data of a row in edit mode:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your URL',
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; 
    charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify($("#GridName").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.select())
});
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know your scenario i think you might want to perform similar thing:

```
 $("#btnSave").click(function () {
                var grddatasource= = $("#GridEmployee").data("kendoGrid");
                var DTO = JSON.stringify(grddatasource);//Convert javascript object to JSON object             
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'your URL' 
                    cache: false,type: 'POST',contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',data: DTO,dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('Created');
                        
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                        $('#error').text('Error: ' + err);
                        alert('Error: ' + err);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {alert('Your Msg !!');}
        });
```

**EDIT**
You have to include the following in the kendo grid for enabling popup editing:

```
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
```

and You have to add the command button in the Kendo Grid (google search) and you have to add the following :

```
.DataSource(dataSource =>
  dataSource.Ajax()
    .Model(model =>
    {
      model.Id(x => x.Id);
    })
    .Read(read => read.Url("your URL").Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
    .Create(create => create.Url("your URL").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
    .Update(update => update.Url("your URL").Type(HttpVerbs.Put))
    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Url("your URL").Type(HttpVerbs.Delete))
)
```

**Edit**
Add a save button on the toolbar of kendogrid

```
.ToolBar(toolbar => {
  toolbar.Save(); // add save button to grid toolbar (If you want InBuilt method)
})
```

**Or I think you want to Save the Grid Separately then using JQuery:**

```
<button type="button" id="save">Save</button>
```

then add the following jQuery:

```
$("#save").on("click", function () {
  $("#Segment").data("kendoGrid").saveChanges();
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried it and it goes to server side. but How can I have the grid's data on server side and save them in database?

Comment: i think you want to save the row of the grid not the entire grid.. If yes see my edit

Comment: I'm so thankful. But I want to save the grid when the submit button is clicked. I need all the rows and other data(<input>) on the form to be saved by one click. The grid is not bind to any data source and the data is just in client.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that You can always get submitted row data from options object.

```
create : function(options) {
                            console.log("Create");
                            console.log(options.data);
```